# htaccess: subfolder 2 levels to domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, symfony

After reading lot of answer I still need help.

I know my problem isn't hard to solve so could you help me please ?

I would like my .htaccess file redirects "www.mysite.com/symfony/web" to "www.mysite.com"

When my app was located at www.mysite.com/web I used this htaccess rule and it worked fine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]     
</IfModule>
```

Now I've created a new folder called "symfony" located at "www.mysite.com/symfony and I put my app into it. I need a new htaccess rule.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ symfony/web/$1 [QSA,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the solution.

Place the htaccess in root path and just add the name of subfolder to the htaccess rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ symfony/web/$1 [QSA,L]     
</IfModule>
```

The problem was I needed to move the location of my htacess due to the creation of a new subfolder